# SQL Server: Czech column name

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get an `.xml` feed using PHP but the problem is with selecting the data from the SQL Server database.

```
$version = mssql_query('SELECT tabVozy.[Číslo vozu] AS WagonNumberFreight FROM [RykoPlus].[dbo].[tabVozy]');
```

The result of this query is: `bool(false)`.

I identified that the problem lies in the Czech column name ('Číslo vozu').
When I tried

```
SELECT tabVozy.[Majitel] AS OwnerCompanyCode  
FROM [RykoPlus].[dbo].[tabVozy]
```

It was perfectly fine.

Is there a way to handle the column name? I can not rename these columns.

Comment: did you try tabVozy.[\`Číslo vozu\`] or \`tabVozy\`.\`Číslo vozu\`?

Comment: If you cannot rename the columns than perhaps you can create a view and than use that view instead of the table ?

Comment: i tried the backticks but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Im sorry, i forgot write it here. I have alias in the code:
tabVozy.[Číslo vozu] AS WagonNumberFreight

But it still gives me bool(false) bcs of that czech column name

Comment: The best that I can suggest you is to create a `VIEW` from your table and use non-Czech column names in it then query over that VIEW ;).

Comment: That query works fine in SQL Server Management Studio. I wonder if there's something strange going on with the character encoding of your file, or if it's an issue with the mssql driver. Is your PHP source file saved as UTF-8 character encoding? Or is it perhaps Windows 1252? I'm guessing the latter might be more likely to cause a problem...

Comment: MS SQL Server works fine with `àéçãüî` and other characters not used in english. The problem can be the enconding at PHP side. Try changing the  source file encoding

Comment: I tried the encoding of the php file, but it didnt helped. The new view solved the problem.